# Redelivery Policy in Camel

Tags: java, xml, apache-camel

I've a small route and I would like to use custom redelivery policy to repeat sending messages to an endpoint, but the behaviour is quite strange. It looks like a redeliveryPolicy is repeating only an error throwing. I was trying to send all exchange to the begin of the route but then the policy is not working cause is creating every time:

```
        <route id="sampleRoute">
            <from uri="direct:anotheRoute" />
            <to uri="nmr:kaboom" />
            <choice>
                <when>
                    <xpath>//result = 'true'</xpath>
                    <to uri="direct:anotherAnotherRoute" />
                </when>
                <otherwise>
                    <throwException ref="redeliveryException" />
                </otherwise>
            </choice>
            <onException>
                <exception>java.net.SocketException</exception>
                <exception>java.net.ConnectException</exception>
                <exception>my.custom.error.RedeliveryException</exception>
                <redeliveryPolicy ref="customRedeliveryPolicy" />
                <to uri="direct:anotheRoute" />
            </onException>
        </route>
```

What I'm doing wrong? I would like to repeat my request with intervals when an error occurs. My camel version is 2.6

logs:

```
16:29:43,780 | DEBUG | cc5bd91-thread-1 | DefaultListableBeanFactory       |  | 59 - org.springframework.beans - 3.0.5.RELEASE | Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'RedeliveryPolicy'
16:29:43,780 | DEBUG | cc5bd91-thread-1 | DefaultErrorHandler              |  | 68 - org.apache.camel.camel-core - 2.6.0.fuse-03-01 | Failed delivery for exchangeId: ID-1NVC-52527-1436958153799-314-4. On delivery attempt: 0 caught: my.custom.error.RedeliveryException
16:29:43,780 | DEBUG | cc5bd91-thread-1 | RedeliveryPolicy                 |  | 68 - org.apache.camel.camel-core - 2.6.0.fuse-03-01 | Sleeping for: 60 millis until attempting redelivery
16:29:43,840 | DEBUG | cc5bd91-thread-1 | DefaultListableBeanFactory       |  | 59 - org.springframework.beans - 3.0.5.RELEASE | Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'RedeliveryPolicy'
16:29:43,840 | DEBUG | cc5bd91-thread-1 | DefaultErrorHandler              |  | 68 - org.apache.camel.camel-core - 2.6.0.fuse-03-01 | Failed delivery for exchangeId: ID-1NVC-52527-1436958153799-314-4. On delivery attempt: 1 caught: my.custom.error.RedeliveryException
16:29:43,840 | DEBUG | cc5bd91-thread-1 | RedeliveryPolicy                 |  | 68 - org.apache.camel.camel-core - 2.6.0.fuse-03-01 | Sleeping for: 60 millis until attempting redelivery
16:29:43,900 | DEBUG | cc5bd91-thread-1 | DefaultListableBeanFactory       |  | 59 - org.springframework.beans - 3.0.5.RELEASE | Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'RedeliveryPolicy'
16:29:43,900 | DEBUG | cc5bd91-thread-1 | DefaultErrorHandler              |  | 68 - org.apache.camel.camel-core - 2.6.0.fuse-03-01 | Failed delivery for exchangeId: ID-1NVC-52527-1436958153799-314-4. On delivery attempt: 2 caught: my.custom.error.RedeliveryException
16:29:43,900 | DEBUG | cc5bd91-thread-1 | RedeliveryPolicy                 |  | 68 - org.apache.camel.camel-core - 2.6.0.fuse-03-01 | Sleeping for: 60 millis until attempting redelivery
16:29:43,960 | DEBUG | cc5bd91-thread-1 | DefaultListableBeanFactory       |  | 59 - org.springframework.beans - 3.0.5.RELEASE | Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'RedeliveryPolicy'
16:29:43,960 | DEBUG | cc5bd91-thread-1 | DefaultErrorHandler              |  | 68 - org.apache.camel.camel-core - 2.6.0.fuse-03-01 | Failed delivery for exchangeId: ID-1NVC-52527-1436958153799-314-4. On delivery attempt: 3 caught: my.custom.error.RedeliveryException
16:29:43,960 | DEBUG | cc5bd91-thread-1 | RedeliveryPolicy                 |  | 68 - org.apache.camel.camel-core - 2.6.0.fuse-03-01 | Sleeping for: 60 millis until attempting redelivery
16:29:44,020 | DEBUG | cc5bd91-thread-1 | DefaultListableBeanFactory       |  | 59 - org.springframework.beans - 3.0.5.RELEASE | Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'RedeliveryPolicy'
16:29:44,020 | DEBUG | cc5bd91-thread-1 | DefaultErrorHandler              |  | 68 - org.apache.camel.camel-core - 2.6.0.fuse-03-01 | Failed delivery for exchangeId: ID-1NVC-52527-1436958153799-314-4. On delivery attempt: 4 caught: my.custom.error.RedeliveryException
16:29:44,020 | DEBUG | cc5bd91-thread-1 | RedeliveryPolicy                 |  | 68 - org.apache.camel.camel-core - 2.6.0.fuse-03-01 | Sleeping for: 60 millis until attempting redelivery
16:29:44,080 | DEBUG | cc5bd91-thread-1 | DefaultListableBeanFactory       |  | 59 - org.springframework.beans - 3.0.5.RELEASE | Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'RedeliveryPolicy'
16:29:44,080 | DEBUG | cc5bd91-thread-1 | DefaultErrorHandler              |  | 68 - org.apache.camel.camel-core - 2.6.0.fuse-03-01 | Failed delivery for exchangeId: ID-1NVC-52527-1436958153799-314-4. On delivery attempt: 5 caught: my.custom.error.RedeliveryException
16:29:44,081 | DEBUG | cc5bd91-thread-1 | NMR                              |  | 81 - org.apache.servicemix.nmr.core - 1.4.0.fuse-03-01 | Channel org.apache.servicemix.nmr.core.ChannelImpl@7dc124e5 dispatching exchange: [
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its not strange, Camel's error handler and redelivery performs from the step that failed, not from the start of the route.

You can instead of throwing the error call the `direct:anotherRoute` again, only problem is that if you do this too frequent your call-stack may get too deep.

What you can do instead is to put that `nmr:kaboom` into a separate route, and configure it to have `noErrorHandler`, and then from the first route, call it with `direct:`, then the error handler can redeliver the entire route from the beginning.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for this explanation. I will post the correct answer:

```
        <route id="sampleRoute">
            <from uri="direct:anotheRoute" />
            <to uri="direct:kaboom" />
            <onException>
                <exception>java.net.SocketException</exception>
                <exception>java.net.ConnectException</exception>
                <exception>my.custom.error.RedeliveryException</exception>
                <redeliveryPolicy ref="customRedeliveryPolicy" />
            </onException>
        </route>
        <route errorHandlerRef="noErrorHandler">
            <from uri="direct:kaboom />
            <to uri="nmr:kaboom/>
            <choice>
                <when>
                    <xpath>//result = 'true'</xpath>
                    <to uri="direct:anotherAnotherRoute" />
                </when>
                <otherwise>
                    <throwException ref="redeliveryException" />
                </otherwise>
            </choice>
        </route>
```

and declaration inside beans:

```
<bean id="noErrorHandler" class="org.apache.camel.builder.NoErrorHandlerBuilder"/>
```